# Python: How to stop time.time() from printing multiple times

Tags: python, time

I have the following code:

```
       if (len(circles[0, :])) == 5:
            start = time.time()

        if (len(circles[0, :])) == 1:
            end = time.time()

            t = timedelta(seconds=end-start)

            print(t)
```

This is the output i am currently getting

```
0:00:01.615148
0:00:01.633098
0:00:01.673181
0:00:01.698559
0:00:01.754114
0:00:01.769037
0:00:01.816332
0:00:01.833286
0:00:01.864809
0:00:01.900769
0:00:01.932686
0:00:01.966634
0:00:01.998760
0:00:02.032730
0:00:02.088114
0:00:02.108045
```

I am trying to get it so when 5 circles are detected the timer starts and when only 1 circle is detected it ends, this might be a simple solution but i have not found it yet.... this is the output i am looking for

```
0:00:02.108045
```

Comment: If that's really your exact code, then clearly you are detecting one circle many times.

Comment: Clearly?? How? I've programmed it so the timer starts when 5 circles are detected, when one circle is left the timer stops and prints how long it took for 4 circles to disappear, but my issue is that it prints numerous different times and i'm not sure how too adapt it.

Comment: Your code looks incorrectly indented. It seems that there is a loop outside those ifs, may be you should add them

Comment: I have a ```for i in circles[0, :7]:```   Above it.. there are no more loops in the program

Answer (score 0):

1. fix your indentation.
2. once you find 1 circle, just end the loop.
3. every time 1 circle is detected, save the frame with the bounding box on the circle (name the frame with the timestamp), that way you can easily debug if you are correctly detecting the circles or not.